# Refreshing Angular App takes to the default state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-routing

I am creating angularjs based Dashboeard, I am using ui.router to create states from json file, 
My topNavbar and states are being created by pages.json file.
My app works fine but when refresh the page with this"localhost:#/map" url it redirects to "localhost:#/dashboard" state.
how I can set the state which user enters in URL?

```
var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
var $stateProviderRef = null;

 myApp.run(function ($q, $rootScope, $state, $http, navbars)
        {
           navbars.load()
            $http.get("js/config/pages.json")
                .success(function (data) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                        var state = {
                            "url": value.url,
                            "templateUrl": value.templateUrl,
                            "controller": value.controller

                        };
                        $stateProviderRef.state(value.sref, state);
                    });


                });
              }

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
        $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;
        $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
    })
```

**pages.json**

```
[
{
    "displayname": "Dashboard",
    "active": true,
    "name": "dashboard",
    "sref": "dashboard",
    "url": "/dashboard",
    "controller": "layoutOneCtrl",
    "templateUrl": "views/dashboard.html",
    "icon": "fa-dashboard",
    "children": [{
        "name": "dashboard"
                }]
            }, {
    "displayname": "Map",
    "open": false,
    "active": false,
    "name": "map",
    "sref": "map",
    "url": "/map",
    "templateUrl": "views/layout1.html",
    "controller": "layoutOneCtrl",
    "icon": "fa-map-marker",
    "children": [{
        "name": "map"
                }]
     }
     .
     . 
     .
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

when you refresh page , your run function called and  read value from pages.json , you need to update pages.json file or you need to save the url value in localstorage or sessionstorage so whenever you refresh the page  you can access url value  from localstorage or sessionstorage.

Comment: Thank Dinesh for response. will it be a good approach to use localstorage?